# I keep getting the Nan when all inputs are numbers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, nan

I'll start off by sayying i know there are multiple questions like this but non solved my issues.
I am currently making a calculator in javascript for a web app and i keep running into the NaN as the output and I am unsure why, here is the code html first then js....

```js
//number of attendees
const num = document.getElementById('attendees').value;
//The percentage that need a place to stay
const per = document.getElementById('percentage').value;
//How many days the event is for
const _eventLength = document.getElementById('eventLength').value;



//The number of people needing rooms
const _percentage = (num, per) => {
  return (num / 100) * per;
};

//Room nights booked
const nightsBooked = (_percentage, _eventLength) => {

  document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = percentage * _eventLength;
};
document.addEventListener('click', _percentage, false);
document.addEventListener('click', nightsBooked, false);
```

```html
<form action="calculator.js" method="get">
  <label for="attendees">How many people will be attending your event?(include staff and anyone else involved!)</label>
  <input type="text" id="attendees">
  <br>
  <label for="percentage">What percentage need a place to stay?</label>
  <input type="text" id="percentage">
  <br>
  <label for="eventLength">How many days is your event?</label>
  <input type="text" id="eventLength">
  <br>
  <p id="res1" style="border: solid 1px; width: 200px; height: 20px;"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calbut1">></button>

</form>
```

As you can see everything is linked up correctly it must be some small bit of code ive missed by mistake and ill remove this if it is but if somone could explain why this isnt working also let me know if you want me to wack it in code pen or something so you can see it in action

Comment: Your function header has `_percentage`, but you use `percentage` (without underscore)

Comment: Also `_percentage` is actually `Event`, not just element. Anyway, there are way too much errors in variable usage.

Comment: Your event listeners don't make sense. An event listener takes an event object as argument, but you have there two arguments and handle them as if they were numbers...

Comment: `const _eventLength` will never update with user input as it's value is set only once

Comment: What is the logic of your naming convention? Why do some variables begin with `_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning values at the very start and none of the input elements have a value at that point. Those "non-value" variables are then used throughout your calculations and, unsurprisingly, will yield a non numeric value...Assuming that the final number is derived when the button is clicked then a single event handler can be assign that does the calculations immediately rather than when, weirdly, there is a click on the `document` itself.

```js
const nightsBooked = () => {

  const attendees = Number(document.getElementById('attendees').value);
  const percentage = Number(document.getElementById('percentage').value);
  const eventLength = Number(document.getElementById('eventLength').value);
  
  const calcpercentage = () => {
    if( !isNaN( attendees ) && !isNaN( percentage ) ){
      return ( attendees / 100 ) * percentage;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = calcpercentage() * eventLength;
};


document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  nightsBooked();
});
```

```html
<form method="get">

  <label for="attendees">How many people will be attending your event?(include staff and anyone else involved!)</label>
  <input type="text" id="attendees">
  <br>
  
  <label for="percentage">What percentage need a place to stay?</label>
  <input type="text" id="percentage">
  <br>
  
  <label for="eventLength">How many days is your event?</label>
  <input type="text" id="eventLength">
  <br>
  
  <p id="res1" style="border: solid 1px; width: 200px; height: 20px;"></p>
  
  <button type="button" id="btn">></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers for the help and explanation I am new to coding hence why it was a mess :)

Comment: I am glad that I was able to offer a little help - good luck with the rest of the coding adventures